# How to restore a database to the latest file in a backup set

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

```
USE ICT;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE ICT
TO DISK = 'E:\Backup\ICT.bak' -- Verwijder dit bestand a.u.b.
GO

RESTORE DATABASE ICT_TEST FROM disk = 'E:\Backup\ICT.bak'
WITH REPLACE, 
   MOVE 'ICT' TO 'E:\DATA\ICT_TEST.mdf',
   MOVE 'ICT_log' TO 'E:\DATA\ICT_TEST_log.ldf'
GO
```

This script makes a backup from my PROD DB en restores it to my TEST DB. When i run this script twice, i get the first backup in the file. How can i make sure that the latest backup will be restored over the TEST DB? I understand that you can tell SQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE ICT_TEST FROM disk = 'E:\Backup\ICT.bak'
WITH REPLACE, FILE = 2
```

But i don't want to do this every time.

Comment: if you are using the same backup file name (ICT.bak) every time you backup, its better to use `INIT`. This way the previous file gets overwritten.

Comment: Yes, 100% agreed, stop combining multiple backups in the same file. What does this gain you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer (read the comments in the script) :

if you are using the same backup file name (`ICT.bak`) every time you backup, its better to use `INIT`. This way the previous file gets overwritten.

```
USE master -- here no need to use the name of the database that you are backing up. Other RDBMS like SybaseASE will thorw an error saying that you should be in master db to run a backup command
GO
BACKUP DATABASE ICT
TO DISK = 'E:\Backup\ICT.bak' -- Verwijder dit bestand a.u.b.
with init, stats =10
--, compression -- if you are using sql server 2008R2 standard and up (enterprise has compression feature). Make sure that backup compression is enabled using sp_configure option.
GO

RESTORE DATABASE ICT_TEST FROM disk = 'E:\Backup\ICT.bak'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
   MOVE 'ICT' TO 'E:\DATA\ICT_TEST.mdf',
   MOVE 'ICT_log' TO 'E:\DATA\ICT_TEST_log.ldf'
GO
```

Comment: Great time saver.